# Jmeter - Is it possible to pass query through variable

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to pass query through variable? What I need is:
1. Get multiple queries from csv file.
2. Execute them one by one.
3. Store results

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried beacuse it should work

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by using CSV Data Set config and Bean shell post processor.

Step 1: Need to read queries from CSV file.

[image: csv config]

Step 2: Use JDBC request to query the database. I'm assuming that you already created database JDBC pool with the help of JDBC Connection Configuration

[image: jdbc config]

Step 3: Use Bean Shell post processor to save the results into a file.
[image: bean shell]

Answer (score 0):

1. To read queries from the file one by one you can use [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) like:

   [image: JMeter SQL Query From File]
2. To store the output you can go for different options,

   - [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener if query result is a simple/singe value
   - If your query result is more complex, i.e. you need to iterate the ResultSet object - you will need to do some scripting, check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)
   - If your query generates several JMeter Variables you can get them stored into .jtl results file via [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property.